# Transform a differential equation into Hamiltonian form

Tags: dynamical-systems, quantum-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis, hamilton-equations

I am currently doing the following exercise in the book Modern Geometry - Methods and Applications Part I by Dubrovin, Fomenko, and Novikov.

> Exercise 33.4.1: Consider the differential equation
> \begin{align}\label{1}\tag{1}
> \dot{u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\delta S}{\delta u},
> \end{align}
> on the space of functions $u(x)$ periodic with period $T$, and satisfying
> $$
> \int_{x_0}^{x_0+T} u(x) d x=0,
> $$
> where $S=S[u]$ is a functional of the form
> $$
> S[u]=\int_{x_0}^{x_0+T} L\left(u, u^{\prime}, \ldots\right) d x .
> $$
> Transform the differential equation into standard Hamiltonian form. (Hint. Work with the Fourier coefficients $u_n$ of the function $u$, determined by $u=$ $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} u_n e^{(2 \pi i n x) / T}$.)

First, I think \eqref{1} is
$$
u'(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{\delta S}{\delta u}(u(x),u'(x),u''(x),\ldots)\right).
$$
Then, the equation is equivalent to
\begin{align}\tag{2}\label{2}
u(x)=\frac{\delta S}{\delta u}(u(x),u'(x),u''(x),\ldots)+C
\end{align}
for some constant $C$.

> Question 1: I wonder if my understanding is correct. The exercise write $\partial / \partial x$ instead of $d/dx$.

Pretend that what I understand is correct. Then, I have the following attempts:

The space we consider is identified as $\ell^{2}$ space with elements $(u_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ (Note that $u_{0} = 0$ and $u_{-n} = \overline{u_{n}}$.) via the Fourier expansion.

Then, I plug the Fourier expansion $u=\sum u_ne^{(2\pi inx)/T}$ into the differential equation \eqref{2} and compare the coefficient of $e^{(2\pi inx)/T}$. The LHS of \eqref{2} is easy. However, I have no idea how to deal with the RHS of \eqref{2} (instead of brute Force expansion and calculation).

> Question 2: How to deal with the RHS of \eqref{2} after plug in $u=\sum u_ne^{(2\pi inx)/T}$.

Alternatively, I think we may directly transform the ODE \eqref{2} into a system of $1$-st order Hamiltonian equations. That is, I need to find the Hamiltonian $H(p_1,\ldots,q_1,\ldots)$ such that
\begin{align}
q_{i}'(x) = \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}(p(x),q(x))\quad p_{i}'(x) = -\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}(p(x),q(x))
\end{align}
I attempt to consider $H(p_i,q_i) = \sum p_i q_{i} + \{\text{blabla}\}$ and set $q_{i} = u^{(i)}(x)$. However, I cannot find the correct $H$ and $p_{i}s$.

> Question 3: How to find $H$ and $p_{i}$ so that the ODE \eqref{2} transform into the Hamilton type equation.

Comment: Since your functional contains higher-oder derivatives, the definition of the Hamiltonian has to be adapted; the following document explains how to proceed : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://cds.cern.ch/record/258605/files/P00020903.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjh76ro0-aCAxWh1AIHHe1oBvYQFnoECBUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0A2vyejOKCttisunZm4uDt